# How data is inserted in catalogsearch_fulltext table?

Tags: magento-1.9, search, fulltext

I have two stores. The catalogsearch_fulltext table contains values for a product available in both stores as shown in screen shot below.

[image]

The values inserted in **name** column are

**SURGICAL STEEL DOUBLE JEWELED NAVEL BANANA SURGICAL STEEL DOUBLE SWAROVSKI CRYSTAL JEWELED NAVEL BANANA SURGICAL STEEL DOUBLE SWAROVSKI CRYSTALS JEWELED NAVEL BANANA**

and

**BNDJ SURGICAL STEEL DOUBLE SWAROVSKI CRYSTALS JEWELED NAVEL BANANA SURGICAL STEEL DOUBLE JEWELED NAVEL BANANA**

for store_id 3 and 1 respectively. The **data_index** values are same.

This is a group product. All product attribute values are same. There is only difference in number of associated products.

On what basis the values for column 'name' are inserted in table catalogsearch_fulltext?

**EDIT**:

I have made associated products same and re-indexed data but still 'name' column values are different.

Answer (score 1):

The fulltext indexer is collecting all values for all attributes for composite products like bundle, group and configurable products.

```
\Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Indexer_Fulltext::_isProductComposite
```

Unfortunately I can't find the part where the values are concatenated.

UPDATE:
As piyush commented, the value is built in:

```
\Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext::_rebuildStoreIndex
```

Comment: Thanks Fabian. I have found the function _rebuildStoreIndex. It is defined in class  Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext. I am debugging it.